# Result Column ordering different from Query using XSD

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xsd

I am querying a MySQL database via xsd/dataset in C#. When I query it within the .xsd designer, I get the column order as I used it in the SELECT statement.

For example:

```
Select a, b, c
From tbl
```

Will return the columns ordered as a,b,c.

The problem is that when I change the query and adding alias to another column, the xsd designer put that column at the end in the column name list. So now if A is the column that I used change its alias, it will order the result with that column at the end, instead of being first. The SELECT column order wasn't changed and it is the same as before.

How can I make sure that xsd queries will return the columns ordered as they are in the SELECT statement?

Using: Visual Studio 2013, C#, .NET 4.5